# Replace multiple values in file in python

Tags: python, shell

I have shell file test.sh and it has following data in it:-

export HOME=/some/path/to/directory

export VERSION=89

export CONNECTION=database_connection

Now I want to update the values HOME, VERSION and CONNECTION in the shell script file using python.
How can I do this in python?

Comment: Please specify whether you want to modify the shell script via Python or whether you need to use these variables in a Python script but set different values?

Comment: Using python I just want to modify values in shell file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with simple search and replace

`re.M` is used for multiline

```
import re

s = open('test.sh', 'r').read()

s = re.sub(r"^export HOME=.*$", "export HOME=/new/path", s, 0, re.M)
s = re.sub(r"^export VERSION=.*$", "export VERSION=new_version", s, 0, re.M)
s = re.sub(r"^export CONNECTION=.*$", "export CONNECTION=new_connection", s, 0, re.M)

open('test.sh', 'w').write(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file, and then parse out the tokens. Keep a dictionary with the replacements, and then write the line back to a *new* file.

```
import re
exp = r'export (\w+)=(.*?)'

lookup = {'HOME': '/new/value', 'VERSION': 55}

with open('somefile.sh', 'r') as f, open('new.sh', 'w') as o:
    for line in f:
       if len(line.strip()):
          if not line.startswith('#'):  # This will skip comments
              tokens = re.findall(exp, line.strip())
              for match in tokens:
                  key, value = match
                  o.write('export {}={}\n'.format(key, lookup.get(key, value)))
              else:
                  # no lines matched, write the original line back
                  o.write(line)
           else:
              o.write(line) # write out the comments back
```

I'll explain the important bits, the rest is just common file writing loops.

The regular expression will result in a list of tuples, each tuple having the matched key and value:

```
>>> re.findall(r'export (\w+)=(.*)', i)
[('HOME', '/some/path/to/directory'),
 ('VERSION', '89'),
 ('CONNECTION', 'database_connection')]
```

The `get()` method of dictionaries will fetch a key, and if it doesn't exist, return a default value of None, but you can overwrite the default value to be returned. Exploiting this we have this line:

```
o.write('export {}={}\n'.format(key, lookup.get(key, value)))
```

This is saying *"if the key exists in the lookup dictionary, return the value, otherwise return the original value from the file"*, in other words if we don't want to overwrite the value of the key, just write the original value back to the file.